# Check if date is specific number of years ago

Tags: android, kotlin, jodatime

The task is to find out if user's age (represented via unix timestamp) is more than 18 (or any number for this matter) years. It's important to make sure this algorithm has precision up to single day (e.g. if user was born precisely 365 days ago).

There is absolutely no need to use huge libraries such as JodaTime for such a simple job.

Answer (score 1):

There have been quite several answers to this question already, however all of them use JodaTime (which is hideous), complicated calculations or unreliable (you can not just multiply number of years * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 and forget about leap years).

The accurate and simple solution would be:

```
fun check(dateOfBirth: Long, minYears: Int): Boolean {
    val timestampThen = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        add(Calendar.YEAR, -minYears)
    }.timeInMillis
    return dateOfBirth <= timestampThen
}
```